# how to echo all products in shopping cart to paypal

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, paypal, shopping-cart

I am just learning the ropes of php and am building an e-commerce site for a uni project, I have the whole thing built and setup payment via paypal, which I've done through a few tutorials.

When I am transferring to paypal I want to display; the item name, price and quantity for each item in the cart, within the order summary.

In its current state http://pastie.org/3127790 , the code is only displaying the top item in the cart in the order summary on paypal, I think I need to implement a foreach loop to tell the code to echo all rows in the cart, but am unsure what exactly to loop and how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance, Michael

Code snippet

```
      <?php

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM podcasts WHERE id_podcasts IN (";
          foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value){
            $sql .= $id . ",";  
          }
          $sql = substr($sql,0,-1).") ORDER BY name ASC";
          $query = mysql_query($sql);
          $total_price = 0;
          if(!empty($query)){
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $subtotal = $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_podcasts']]['quantity']*$row['price'];
            $total_price += $subtotal;
            ?>

            <?php
            $ppname = $row['name'];
            $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_podcasts']]['name'] = $row['name'];
            $ppquantity = $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_podcasts']]['quantity'];
            $ppprice= $row['price'];
            ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_podcasts']]['quantity'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo "&pound;" . $row['price'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo"&pound;" .  $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_podcasts']]['quantity']*$row['price'];?></td>
              </tr>
            <?php
          } }
          ?>


  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><span>Total Price:</td></span>
    <td><span><?php echo"&pound;" .  $total_price;?></td></span>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="payme_1321908135_biz@immbudden.com"> <!-- change to your paypal address -->
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $ppquantity;?>"> <!-- do not change, since you refer to it all via the database -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $ppname;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $ppprice;?>"> <!-- change here -->
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['emailaddress'];?>"> <!-- if you store their purchase in a database, reference the database number here -->
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://shop.residencyradio.com/success.php">
<span class="input_btn"><input type="submit" name="purchase" value="Purchase" ></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you edit and paste on hear the exact part you need help with.

Comment: Hi andy, check the edit of my original question, i've added the code there.

Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only answer your question. I don't sure about the effectiveness of all your code.
I have made some changes in some of your pasted code:

```
<?php
$output_paypal = ''; // container for output for paypal form
$total_items = 0;

if ( ! empty($query))
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $subtotal = $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_podcasts']]['quantity'] * $row['price'];
        $total_price += $subtotal;

        $ppname = htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
        $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_podcasts']]['name'] = $row['name']; // this assigment seems not useful
        $ppquantity = $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_podcasts']]['quantity'];
        $ppprice = $row['price'];

        $total_items ++;

        $output_paypal .= <<<EOM
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_{$total_items}" value="$ppname">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_{$total_items}" value="$ppquantity">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_{$total_items}" value="$ppprice">
EOM; // heredoc syntax (may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon.)
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $ppname; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ppquantity; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "&pound;" . $ppprice; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo"&pound;" . $ppquantity * $ppprice; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
?>


<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="payme_1321908135_biz@immbudden.com">

    <?php echo $output_paypal; ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['emailaddress']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://shop.residencyradio.com/success.php">
    <span class="input_btn"><input type="submit" name="purchase" value="Purchase" ></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi dude,

Thanks for your reply, I am aware that some of the code is probably not that effective, I am in the early stages of learning the language, so apologies for that.

The code that you created does almost work, however in paypal it bunches all of the items together as one item rather than showing each individual item on the product summary.

You can see exactly what I mean by going to http://shop.residencyradio.com and adding a few items to the cart and going through to the payment page.

Thanks!

Comment: just tried it there but this time it isn't outputting anything :S new version on http://shop.residencyradio.com

Comment: @michael Really? `$output_paypal` is populated in the `while` loop. And then is `echo' ed inside the form. In any case I showed the right way to achieve your requirement. Just play with it. Good luck and persevere! o/\o

Comment: yea, not sure why, because reading through it I can make sense that it should populate it :/ Il keep looking at it and see if I can do anything with it. Could it be something to do with <<<EOM ? Im not even too sure what that does. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: <<<EOM (very useful in multi-line outputs): [heredoc syntax](http://cl.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)  `the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except possibly a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon.`

Comment: Change `<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">` to `<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">` -- _xclick is for single items, _cart is for carts. Also set `<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">`. More examples at: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_cart_upload

Comment: :D @Robert you have just made my day! that made it work, I think I pretty much understand why it wasn't working originally either. Big thanks to NomikOS as well, I really appreciate your help guys, that small detail has been bugging me for the past day :)

Comment: by the way @NomikOS I will give you the credit for the answer now too!

Comment: Great! Yes, the info `_xclick is for single items, _cart is for carts` is very useful... Thanks as well...

Answer (score 0):

The thing is how to create a view cart for each user seperately that paypal link creates a global cart for all users on my site